All points of a convex space curve are extreme
Let $\gamma$ be a simple closed curve in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with nowhere vanishing curvature. I think I read in several places that if $\gamma$ belongs to the boundary of its convex hull, then it cannot intersect any line more than twice, which means that all points of the curve are extreme points of its convex hull.
I believe this statement to be true, but I am missing a proof. Can anybody help me obtain one?

Such a curve $\gamma$ is strictly convex, and from this the desired properties follow.
